# How to run Argon2 on a Node.js server on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, argon2-ffi

I'm curently building a web app on Google App Engine Standard env. using Node.js 10.16.3. I would like to use [Argon2 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/argon2). Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to install it locally on Windows7 and have no idea how on gcloud either.

It is said on the package page that:

> "Before installing : You MUST have a node-gyp global install before proceeding with install, along with GCC >= 5 / Clang >= 3.3. On Windows, you must compile under Visual Studio 2015 or newer."

I've installed node-gyp globally `npm install -g node-gyp` as well as Python lastest version which is required. I also installed [GCC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/) and then used `npm install argon2` to install the package where my project is. I'm not sure to understand the Visual Studio part.

When trying to run the serveur with `npm start`, I get this error:

```
Error: myproject\node_modules\argon2\lib\binding\argon2.node is not a valid application
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:807:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\myproject\node_modules\argon2\argon2.js:9:56)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\myproject\www\server\server.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myproject@0.0.1 start: `node www/server/server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myproject@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.
```

Am I missing something ? `node-gyp` are also not recognized

Comment: Hey, what version of Node are you using? App Engine Flex or Standard?

Comment: Hi, I've Node v10.16.3 and I'm using Standard App Engine environment.

Comment: I just tried to follow this guide but got no result. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/03/27/node-gyp-windows/

Answer (score 1):

I found the following feature [request](https://issuetracker.google.com/117811339) about implementing the library in GAE standard, this is also interesting, can you try to do this with GAE flex? I think the library might not be implemented in standard. 
As in flex you have customizable runtimes, it might allow you to do it.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57433618/11928097) other thread as well, I think it might contain useful information.

Hope this helps.